# Подсчет слов в строке, не используя функции стандартной библиотеки языка Си

Tags: c, строки

Задание:

Написать программу для подсчета слов в строке. Строка передается в функцию в
качестве параметра. При реализации функции запрещается пользоваться функциями стандартной библиотеки языка C. Под термином «слово» понимается любая
последовательность символов, ограниченная любым количеством пробелов и/или
символом начала/конца строки.

Как реализовать без использования функций стандартной библиотеки, есть какие-нибудь идеи?

UPD:

Рабочий код с вводом через консоль. Спасибо за помощь!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int Words(char * c)
{
    int i, flag, cnt;

    for (i = 0, flag = 0, cnt = 0; c[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (c[i] == ' ' || c[i] == ',' || c[i] == '.'|| c[i] == '-') flag = 0;
        else
        {
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                cnt++;
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Всего слов = %zu\n", cnt);
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int i;
    char c[1024];
    printf("Введите предложение, чтобы посчитать кол-во слов: \n");
    gets_s(c);
    Words(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я бы прошелся циклом по строке и искал разделители (пробелы, символы начала/конца строки). На каждой итерации храним предыдущий символ. Если текущий символ = разделитель, а предыдущий символ разделителем не является, то "позади" осталось слово, а значит увеличиваем счетчик. В противном случае - счетчик не увеличиваем. Из особенностей - первая итерация цикла (не забыть правильно присвоить "предыдущему" символу фиктивное значение). Это на "вскидку", конечно

Comment: Ну а в чём собственно проблема? Покажите, как вы пытались имплементировать что-то типа `static bool my_isspace(char c) {...} static char *my_strtok(...) {  ...while (!my_isspace(*p++)); ... }`

Comment: Количество слов содержит не переменная флаг, а переменная cnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  char * c;

  int i, flag, cnt;

  for (i =0, flag =0, cnt =0; c[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
      if (c[i] == ' ') flag = 0;
      else
      {
        if (flag == 0)
        {
         cnt++;
         flag = 1;
        } 
      }
      if (c[i] == '\0') break;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100 // Maximum string size

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_SIZE];
    int i, words;

    /* Input string from user */
    printf("Enter any string: ");
    gets(str);

    i = 0;
    words = 1;

    /* Runs a loop till end of string */
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        /* If the current character(str[i]) is white space */
        if(str[i]==' ' || str[i]=='\n' || str[i]=='\t')
        {
            words++;
        }

        i++;
    }

    printf("Total number of words = %d", words);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что точная копия вышего предыдущего ответа так же отвечает и на вопрос в этой теме? Что ваш ответ даёт нового?